# Android Code Style in Intellij Idea / Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, coding-style, intellij-idea, android-studio

Before Android Studio, I was using [android-formatting.xml](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml) as Code Style in Eclipse.

How can I setup Android Studio / Intellij Idea to format code as in Eclipse?

**UPDATE**

I tried Eclipse Code Formatter plugin. It seems to work, but you cannot edit any setting at all. My team prefers 120 columns instead of 100.

I tried @CrossleSong answer too. It's a bit tricky, but more powerful. You can save this

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/ide/intellij/codestyles/AndroidStyle.xml

as *Android.xml* and copy it to AndroidStudio/Intellij codestyles folder: for me is

`~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview/codestyles`

Now you can select Android as Code Style in Android Studio Preferences.

Comment: Turns out, if you restart Android Studio, then you don't have to rename the AndroidStyle.xml file, which might be a better approach just in case a future update tweaks the original Android.xml file. Just choose the right scheme under preferences > code style > java

Comment: With the new Android Studio Beta release you can add the xml file here:

~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta/codestyles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download the [development](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/) repo from Android source. The `development/ide/intellij` folder includes code style, templates...

Answer (score 6):

**Instructions to use Eclipse XML formatter in Android Studio**:

1. File -> Settings -> Plugins
2. click 'Browse repositories' button, enter 'Eclipse Code Formatter' in the search field and install the plugin.
3. Restart Android Studio.
4. File -> Settings -> Other Settings -> Eclipse Code Formatter (if you cannot find it, then use search field for that)
5. select 'Use the Eclipse code formatter', browse your xml style file and press OK button to close the Settings.

I hope I wrote instructions clear. Let me know in case you didn't understand.

Comment: I cant find 'File -> Settings -> Other Settings' in android studio

Comment: @Vihar, maybe you have another Android Studio version, this is how it looks like in mine http://prntscr.com/97586q.  Anyway if you cannot find it you can use a search field, just type there 'Eclipse Code Formatter'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the third-party [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=6546) plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

For `Android Studio 1.2.2` and above:

**What didn't work for me:**

Thanks for the question. There are good answers and hints here but for my case where I updated to Android Studio 1.2.2, it didn't work right out of the box. Some answers and [blogs](http://anton46.com/importing-the-official-android-code-style-to-android-studiointellij/) suggested that after downloading the `xml` file,

1. Save the `xml` file to `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/codestyles`.
2. Then restart `AndroidStudio`
3. Go to `Android Studio -> Preferences -> Code Style -> Java` and from `Scheme` dropdown select the scheme name and save.

   However when I put the xml file inside `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/codestyles/` folder it didn't show my scheme name in the `Scheme` dropdown to select from.

**What worked for me:**

After I updated Android Studio to latest version, under `~/Library/Preferences/` in mac, I had two folders: `AndroidStudio` and `AndroidStudio1.2`. For importing the [AndroidStyle.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-5.1.1_r6/ide/intellij/codestyles/AndroidStyle.xml) code style file in the updated Android studio, I had to create a folder named `codestyles` inside `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/` folder, since none existed. Then I saved the `xml` file in there and followed the above [procedure](http://anton46.com/importing-the-official-android-code-style-to-android-studiointellij/). Just saving the file solely in `.../AndroidStudio/codestyles` folder didn't work for me.

Hope it helps someone some day.

Comment: After I tried this, Android Studio 1.5 was always crashing on startup. The only solution that I found was by removing the whole codestyles dir like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34140623/1390874