# Where is the Android Studio codestyle directory?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to set Android Formatter on Android Studio 0.8.4.
But I can't find `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio(Beta)/codestyles` directory.

Where is the codestyles directory?

Reference: [Android Code Style in Intellij Idea / Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710367/android-code-style-in-intellij-idea-android-studio)

Environment

- Mac OS X 10.9.4
- Android Studio 0.8.4

Answer (score 0):

The directory is at `~/.AndroidStudioBeta/config/codestyles` on Linux, should be similar for other OSs (i.e., under user's home directory).

If the `codestyles` sub-directory does not exist, you can simply create it and put your custom style XML file there.

Comment: Thanks.But I can't find ~/.AndroidStudioBeta directory,too.

Comment: @sugoi_wada On OSX, you should probably look at `/Users/<your_username>` folder.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at it but no .AndroidStudioBeta directory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about is something like "C:\Users\.AndroidStudio2.3\config" in which you should create the "codestyles" folder manually. However, I think you don't really have to do this in Android Studio 2.3, go to Settings->Codestyle->XML and click 'Manage' button and 'Import' your xml style file from any where on your local hard drive.