# Android Studio Code Replaced by Auto Generated Code

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
//This class was automatically generated by the
 * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
 * should not be modified by hand.//
```

When I Re opened Android Studio And Open All Files I am Getting Only This Code. No Other Code Is Displaying And When I Generate APK Its Giving Force Stop Error Always

Another Problem I am Facing Is

> Cannot Load Settings From Misc.xml Error On Line 1 , Content Is Not Allowed In Prolog please correct the file content

and the misc.xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="EntryPointsManager">
    <entry_points version="2.0" />
  </component>
  <component name="NullableNotNullManager">
    <option name="myDefaultNullable" value="android.support.annotation.Nullable" />
    <option name="myDefaultNotNull" value="android.support.annotation.NonNull" />
    <option name="myNullables">
      <value>
        <list size="4">
          <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable" />
          <item index="1" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="javax.annotation.Nullable" />
          <item index="2" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.Nullable" />
          <item index="3" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="android.support.annotation.Nullable" />
        </list>
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="myNotNulls">
      <value>
        <list size="4">
          <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull" />
          <item index="1" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="javax.annotation.Nonnull" />
          <item index="2" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull" />
          <item index="3" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="android.support.annotation.NonNull" />
        </list>
      </value>
    </option>
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectLevelVcsManager" settingsEditedManually="false">
    <OptionsSetting value="true" id="Add" />
    <OptionsSetting value="true" id="Remove" />
    <OptionsSetting value="true" id="Checkout" />
    <OptionsSetting value="true" id="Update" />
    <OptionsSetting value="true" id="Status" />
    <OptionsSetting value="true" id="Edit" />
    <ConfirmationsSetting value="0" id="Add" />
    <ConfirmationsSetting value="0" id="Remove" />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" default="true" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes" />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectType">
    <option name="id" value="Android" />
  </component>
  <component name="masterDetails">
    <states>
      <state key="ProjectJDKs.UI">
        <settings>
          <last-edited>1.8</last-edited>
          <splitter-proportions>
            <option name="proportions">
              <list>
                <option value="0.2" />
              </list>
            </option>
          </splitter-proportions>
        </settings>
      </state>
    </states>
  </component>
</project>
```

Comment: Why Are All Your Words Capitalized?

Comment: Check this answer may it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507998/intellij-idea-crashed-and-now-throws-an-error

Comment: Sorry its just a keyboard setting Ive set it now